# Definite integrals u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Please may you explain how did we jump from the step 2 to step 3 in the screenshot (provided below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9aX8.png)

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} \sec x = \sec x \tan x$

Comment: substitute $u =\sec(x)\implies du= \sec(x)\tan(x)\,dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

**Method 1:**

$u=\sec(x) \Rightarrow du = \sec(x)\tan(x)dx$

**Method 2:**

$$\sec(x)\tan(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Substitute $u=\cos(x) \Rightarrow du=-\sin(x)dx$

Can you continue from either one?

Comment: thanks for helping me out

Comment: No problem! Can you please accept the answer if you think it answered your question?